# Is using URL parameters together with body parameters in a POST request a defined security anti-pattern?

Tags: web-application, terminology, design-flaw

It is technically allowed by many programming languages to supply parameters in POST requests **as part of the URL**, similar to a GET request. You can do this **in addition to supplying parameters in the body** of the POST request at the same time. I just stumbled upon an application that's using such POST requests containing URL parameters together with body parameters for several endpoints.

```
POST /endpoint?urlvar=123
Host: example.com
[...]
Content-Length: 11

bodyvar=321
```

This seems to be an invitation for nasty security bugs:

- There is the potential for mistakes when the same parameter is submitted with different values in the URL and in the body within the same request.
- A security filter might only be applied to a parameter in the body while an attacker can supply it via the URL and vice versa.
- Security audits become more difficult and might miss mistakes more easily.
- Many other creative ways this type of complexity creates problems.

I was looking whether this is a defined security anti-pattern in any of the common standards from OWASP or similar organisations, but came up with nothing. I also found several questions on StackOverflow discussion similar issues but not this specific pattern.

**Is this actually considered a security anti-pattern** by any well-respected organisation? And **is there a name for this anti-pattern** that's established?

Comment: Isn't this just a case of breaking the [Single source of truth principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)? Actually, I was surprised that there are frameworks that still allow this.